# NSDictionary to NSData without newline character ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using following code to convert NSDictionary no NSData

```
 NSDictionary *fieldsDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                              [NSNumber numberWithInteger:shownID],@"entry_id",
                              self.placeFormField.formTextField.text,@"name",
                              self.countryFormField.formTextField.text,@"country",
                              self.cityFormField.formTextField.text,@"city",
                              self.contactNumberFormField.formTextField.text,@"contactName",
                              self.contactNumberFormField.formTextField.text,@"phone",

                              self.fromDateFormField.formTextField.text,@"fromDay",
                              self.fromMonthFormField.formTextField.text,@"fromMonth",
                              self.fromYearFormField.formTextField.text,@"fromYear",


                                  nil

                                  ];




    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fieldsDict
                                                       options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];
```

But this conversion putting extra \ and new line character(As shown in following image). so there is problem on server and getting "Invalid format" error.
[image]

How to avoid newline character in NSData? any help will appreciated.

server prints

```
 {"artwork_id"=>"187", "device_auth_key"=>"LR2mt5BD3cvFBICIWnKmMw", "device_user_id"=>"105", "is_private"=>"yes", "mobile_request"=>"yes", "note"=>"Endless Love", "details"=>"{\n  \"breadth\" : \"7\",\n  \"creation_month\" : \"Feb\",\n  \"creation_year\" : \"1994\",\n  \"length\" : \"7\",\n  \"dimensions_in\" : \"Centimeter\",\n  \"is_framed\" : \"Yes\",\n  \"subject_matter\" : \"This is subject Description Manish\",\n  \"height\" : \"7\",\n  \"medium\" : \"Medium 123\",\n  \"creation_date\" : \"2\"\n}", "purchase_info"=>"{\n  \"purchased_date\" : \"21\",\n  \"purchased_from_country\" : \"In\",\n  \"purchase_cost\" : \"99\",\n  \"shipping\" : \"yep Shi\",\n  \"insurance\" : \"100\",\n  \"purchased_from\" : \"BASIC PURCHASE FROM\",\n  \"purchased_from_city\" : \"Pu\",\n  \"purchased_month\" : \"\",\n  \"storage\" : \"yep Sto\",\n  \"framing\" : \"yep fra\",\n  \"purchased_from_contact_name\" : \"Avi Purchaser\",\n  \"purchased_from_contact_number\" : \"872-909--390\",\n  \"purchased_from_contact_email\" : \"rajeev@gmail\",\n  \"purchased_year\" : \"1991\",\n  \"conservation\" : \"yep C\"\n}", "show_at_places"=>"{\n  \"city\" : \"Las Angels\",\n  \"toMonth\" : \"Oct\",\n  \"toYear\" : \"1802\",\n  \"toDay\" : \"1802\",\n  \"description\" : \"City you live before you die\",\n  \"fromDay\" : \"12\",\n  \"entry_id\" : 5128,\n  \"fromMonth\" : \"Sept\",\n  \"name\" : \"Las Angels\",\n  \"phone\" : \"8729093907\",\n  \"country\" : \"NY\",\n  \"contactName\" : \"8729093907\",\n  \"fromYear\" : \"1801\"\n}"}
```

Comment: There are no newline characters

Comment: This is not Swift. – Your debugger output shows the value of `newStr1` which does not even occur in your code. – The backslashes are used in the debugger view to escape embedded quotation marks in the string.

Comment: @MartinR am gettinh "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." response in AFNetworking

Comment: well, what you show there is something completely different from what your code produces, where does that output come from? In general newlines are not a problem for JSON - what you are showing here is not json since `=>` is no a valid part of json IIRC.

Comment: note that the `details` are treated as string, not as sub json object - what are you doing?

Comment: @luk2302 this output from backend given by developer.

Comment: Please give us something to work with here - **YOUR** code is perfectly fine, if the backend has problems with it - that is the backends fault. What you get returned from the server is ... bullshit. Sorry to state it that clearly, but it simply is.

Comment: @luk2302. i am sorry for that. thank you. i will contact with backend team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99199/discussion-between-avijit-nagare-and-luk2302).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the string is the representation of it in the IDE

Consider the following example code you can put in the playground

```
let arr = ["hi" : "message", "bye" : 1234]
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: [])
let string = NSString(data: json,encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
print(string!)
```

That will output

> {"hi":"message","bye":1234}

But your IDE wants to show it to you in a meaning full way. It knows it is a string, therefore it encapsulates the debugger display in `"`. Unfortunately `"` happens to appear a few times in the string itself. The IDE therefore decides to escape the `"` inside the string to make clear that they are not terminating the string but rather are part of the string. That looks like `\"`

If the server gets an *"Invalid format" error* then there is something wrong with the server.

```js
var a = JSON.parse('{"hi":"message","bye":1234}')
document.write(a)
document.write(" - ")
document.write(a.hi)
document.write(" - ")
document.write(a.bye)
```

```js
var a = JSON.parse("{\"hi\":\"message\",\"bye\":1234}")
document.write(a)
document.write(" - ")
document.write(a.hi)
document.write(" - ")
document.write(a.bye)
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, downvote, hmmmm, downvote without reason, hmmmmm :)

Comment: @AvijitNagare yes, but the comments explain pretty much why your question got and deserved downvotes, because your problem question had initially nothing to do with the presented output and even now you are not making clear, what is going on.